# How to calculate origin and position of a weapon which should be "in hands"?

Tags: xna, c#, rotation

I'm currently stuck with my game, which is from the top perspective. I'm currently using these sprites for player: (using the second at the top):

[image]

And here's what I use for my gun

[image]

My problem is that I am not sure how to calculate origin & position to make sure that gun is always in player's hands. This is my code for drawing player and gun

```
spriteBatch.Draw(Textures.Load("player"), new Vector2(playerPosition.X, playerPosition.Y), new Rectangle(35, 2, 27,27), Color.White, player.rotation, new Vector2(playerWidth / 2, playerHeight / 2), 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
spriteBatch.Draw(Textures.Load("Guns/deagle"), new Vector2(playerPosition.X, playerPosition.Y), null,                   Color.White, player.rotation, new Vector2(playerWidth / 2, playerHeight / 2), 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
```

With rotation of 0, I'd need to move my gun to `playerPosition.Y + 15` to make sure gun is in guy's hands, but when I do it, it looks fine but as soon as I rotate him, it's even more weird than now.

Here's how it currently looks like, with my specified code above.

https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/capture-14.mp4?w=40052a2d

All I need is to make sure that gun will be always in guy's hands

Comment: It may be acting weird because your spritesheet is bad. 0 degrees is right/east. So if you you want sprites to face the way your direction input is, sprites needs to be pointing right/east.

Comment: Here's a version that works, where I've fixed the sprites. I'm sure that's what's causing the issues for you. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/992656/permanent/MindWorX.MartinHelp.zip

Comment: @MindWorX: for some reason, no, this is not the case. My rotation calculation works as `Vector2 direction = new Vector2(player.x, player.y) - new Vector2(worldPosition.X, worldPosition.Y);player.rotation = (float)(Math.Atan2(direction.Y, direction.X))`. If I had it the way you described, I had to add 180 degrees to the rotation

Comment: @MindWorX: please, put this as answer and describe "how it works" a bit more? I'd like to accept that one. Is that really matter of the 180 difference in rotation ?

Comment: @MindWorX: oh, I got it. I had completelly switched my logic for calculating player rotation, it means that 0° for your logic was actually 180° for my logic. It works fine now, thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to offset the gun's position based on the rotation of the player. Here's the first formula that comes to mind:

```
x = x + offset*cos(rotation)

y = y + offset*sin(rotation)
```

So in your specific case use this as the gun's position:

```
new Vector2( playerPosition.X + 15 * (float) Math.Cos(player.rotation), playerPosition.Y + 15 * (float) Math.Sin(player.rotation) )
```

Comment: Hmm, unfortunatelly, that's not what I need, but we are near the finish. http://i.imgur.com/cCfoF.png

Comment: I based the code on the fact that you said with rotation = 0 you need a translation of +15 in Y direction. Try swapping the sin and cos.

Comment: Unfortunately it's acting strange when I do so. Take a look at [this](https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/capture-15.mp4?w=f24a20a3) video

Comment: @Martin this answer is probably close - you might try using an ellipse (use different multipliers for X and Y).

Comment: @JonathanDickinson: yeah, I didn't even think about trying to change multipliers. It works perfectly now (with -18): http://i.imgur.com/gfT92.png

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you treat your sprites as a group of sprites.  When rotated, they will all rotate together as a single entity.

This would greatly simplify what you are trying to do.  Have a look at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb194912.aspx

Answer (score 0):

So here's actually how I solved it:

- I had to apply [MindVorX's](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/8957/mindworx) line of code (origin of weapon should be `Vector.Zero`)
- I had to apply [Jannie's](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/u/12894/jannie-pieters) [logic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/22909/12111)
- I had to play with multiplier of Sin & Cos

so after all, it looks like

```
        spriteBatch.Draw(
          Textures.Load("player"),
          new Vector2(player.x, player.y),
          new Rectangle(35, 2, 27, 27),
          Color.White,
          player.rotation,
          new Vector2(27 / 2, 27 / 2), // half a player's width & height
          1f,
          SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
        spriteBatch.Draw(
          Textures.Load("Guns/deagle"),
          new Vector2( player.x - 18 * (float) Math.Cos(player.rotation), player.y + 18 * (float) Math.Sin(player.rotation) ),
          null,
          Color.White,
          player.rotation,
          Vector2.Zero, // zero here is important!
          1f,
          SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
```

which results in

[image]

Thanks all of you