# How to calculate the inverse of a 4*4 opengl transform matrix

Tags: 3d, matrix

I am transforming my camera like any other object. I would like to set the view model matrix to the inverse of this so that I can draw the rest of the objects relative to the camera.

How do i calculate the inverse transformation?

*I construct this matrix from a quaternion and a position vector, if it is easier to find the inverse of these then feel free to post.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to invert a rotation by unit quaternion `q` followed by a translation `v`, you apply a rotation by unit quaternion `q'` followed by a translation `v'` where:

- `q'` = `~q` (conjugate of `q`, *ie.* inverse of rotation `q`)
- `v'` = `-~q v q` (transform of `-v` by the *inverse* of rotation `q`)

If you only do translations and rotations, it is simpler to not use transformation matrices until the final matrix is constructed.

Comment: True, but I think he needs the transformation matrix, to use as a view matrix.

Comment: I was referring to OP's last paragraph. I will reword the last sentence.

Answer (score 4):

Inverting a matrix is a complex task so I'd recommend snatching an implementation from some library. For instance, here's the matrix code from OpenTK, search for the `Invert` method and see how it was implemented.

https://opentk.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/opentk/trunk/Source/OpenTK/Math/Matrix4.cs

But if you're creating your matrix like:

```
RotationMatrix(quaternion) * TranslationMatrix(position)
```

It might be worth trying to do:

```
TranslationMatrix(-position) * RotationMatrix(conjugate(quaternion))
```

Not sure if it will work, but that's how I usually create a view matrix for 2D games, using an angle instead of a quaternion.

Related answer: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/28833/11686

Comment: Shouldn't you use the conjugate of the quat in your second equation? `-quaternion` is a different thing (consider the quat to be `(cos(t), sin(t)*n)` where `|n| =1` is a unit vector. So I reckon it should be `RotationMatrix(inverse(quaternion)) = RotationMatrix(conjugate(quaternion))`. Also, one typically applies the rotation first, then the translation (hope I'm not misunderstanding the idea)..

Comment: @teodron Thanks! I meant the conjugate but did not know the notation for it, nor what to call it, which is why I left a note explaining what I meant, despite the incorrect notation. I figured someone would fill it in in the comments ;-) As for the order of multiplication, see the related answer. The multiplication order is reversed when creating a view matrix, so it should be okay in this case.

Comment: @teodron To make it more clear what I meant, you can get the inverse of a SRT transformation (with scale, rotation, and position parameters) by performing an inverse transformation in reverse order, i.e. a TRS transformation (with -position, -rotation, and 1/scale as parameters). This is easier and cheaper than inverting the entire matrix.

Comment: The fact that \$(ABC)^{-1} = C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}\$ was obvious, that is something that any programmer with the least of Algebra training should know.. I got your idea ;). +1 because you were the first, the second answer doesn't add any new insights!

Comment: @teodron: multiplying two 4×4 matrices requires 64 multiplications. Transforming a vector using a unit quaternion requires at most 28 multiplications. It's of course more complicated than that but your remark is nothing but condescending. If you do not see how the second answer "adds new insight" then maybe *you* need algebra training.

Comment: @SamHocevar Sorry to ask the same thing again but I'm still confused: if he wants a view matrix to pass around to the graphics device, or to the vertex shader, doesn't it rule out the possibility of directly transforming every vertex in the scene with the quaternion? Considering that the view matrix would usually be concatenated with the world and projection matrices before being applied.

Comment: @DavidGouveia a new matrix is still created in the end; but it is cheaper to build that matrix from a new vector `v'` and a new quaternion `q'` than to invert a matrix or even multiply two matrices.

Comment: @SamHocevar I also upvoted your answer! I do respect you and your work :). Ok, keeping things equitable should be moral. Sorry that I offended you so badly to attack my comment in such a way. You are truly right, but the matrix multiplication chain I wrote there was to _underline_ why doing the reverse of those transforms makes sense.. sheesh, didn't know people were so mad about their points and so mad about their skills. Share wisdom.. I'm not the big kahuna here by any means, but I do remember I have a few degrees in applied and theoretical Mathematics.. and they're useless..

Comment: Also, I hope the attribute `no new` _insights_ doesn't rule out the interpretation of "it does provide insights". Maybe I should keep my big mouth shut and stop commenting. I just wanted to point out that Sam's answer was providing very similar info and that this was just the first answer, chronologically. If I was wrong, I do apologize, but it seemed obvious that using quaternions is arithmetically more efficient. Hence my stupid and quite disturbing comment (judging by Sam's reaction). Lastly, this is another [topic](http://devcry.heiho.net/2011/05/quaternion-versus-matrix-performance.html)

Comment: @teodron: don't worry, I wasn't complaining about not getting upvoted. But I would like to stress that while it makes sense to reverse those transformations, it often does not make sense to do them in naïve matrix form because matrix multiplication is expensive. You were saying people usually do rotation first, then translation; that's precisely the "new insight" I was providing.

Comment: Point taken (i.e. _identity_=Rotate(inv(q))*Translate(-pos)*Translate(pos)*Rotate(q) ). Sorry again for any inconveniences!

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of a non-scaling rotation matrix is just its **transpose**.

If you construct a rotation matrix `R` from the quaternion, then the inverse of that rotation matrix (the "unrotation matrix" as it were) is just the transpose of `R`.

The reason this works is because rotation matrices are made up of [orthogonal vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix).

How to handle the translation component depends on if you are translating before the rotation or after the rotation.  In general to "untranslate" by an offset `v`, you just translate by `-v`.